# Thunderbird won't load in UBUNTU 12.04

Tags: thunderbird

Can anyone tell me why my Thunderbird won't load in my newly upgraded UBUNTU 12.04. The error message seems to point to Addons but I cannot get it loaded to look at them. If I compose a new message on its own I can get into the preferences and then to the manage Addons - it trys to load them and then drops out.

Comment: Can you try a new profile to see if the add-ons are really the problem?

Comment: and to create a new profile, you can access profilemanager by running `thunderbird -p` from a terminal or Run dialog ( Alt + F2 )

Answer (score 1):

Went to Thunderbird in Dash-right clicked on ICON-Compose New Message - Help - Restart With Add-ons Disabled - and it now works